# What is the best way to manage custom serializer in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom serializer which contains some other model serializer, data field, and some list field for manage many to many relation. Here is an example.

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a_model_serializer = AModelSerializer()
    b_model_serializer = serializers.ListField(child=CModelSerializer())
    another_field = serializers.CharField()
```

Based on this serializer I have to create some model object and some many to many relation through a third table. Now, what could be the best way to manage this situation.

Comment: Maybe you could use a `SerializerMethodField` to better manipulate the nested fields

Comment: @blueSurfer I think you didn't understood my question. In this(CustomSerializer) serializer I have to create some model instance and some many to many relation. Then I have to return the data with AModelSerializer instance's id and later have to manage update for the serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the create() function for serializers.Serializer. And to manage updates, override the update() function.

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a_model_serializer = AModelSerializer()
    b_model_serializer = serializers.ListField(child=CModelSerializer())
    another_field = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
       print(validated_data)
       # Do your custom create

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
       print(validated_data)
       # Do your custom update
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Comment: if I go for this approach then how I use this serializer in views and what kind of will convenient? Lastly how I'll return value from create and update method?

Comment: Well if you are using DRF then these functions will be called when you send a HTTP POST or PUT request to the web server. It will send a request to the URL for the Viewset you have specified which will call the serializer class to create or update using the data.